# Is this approach wrong?

Tags: calculus

Where have i gone wrong?
$\frac{dq}{dt}=1000\cdot 2^{t}$

$dq=1000\cdot 2^{t}\cdot dt$

$\int\ln dq=\int\ln2000t\cdot dt$

$\ln\int dq=\int\ln2000t\cdot dt$

$\ln(q)+c_1=t\cdot\ln(2000t)-2000t+c_2$

let $C=\pm c_1\pm c_2$

$\ln(q)=t\cdot\ln(2000t)-2000t+C$

$e^{\ln(q)}=e^{t\cdot\ln(2000t)-2000t+C}$

$q(t)=(e^{\ln(2000t)})^{t}\cdot e^{-2000t}\cdot e^C$

let $A=e^C$

$q(t)=A\cdot (2000t)^t\cdot e^{-2000t}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is $\ln(1000\cdot2^t) \ne \ln(2000 t)$. Instead use
$$\ln(a\cdot b) = \ln(a) + \ln(b)\\
\ln(a^b) = b\cdot \ln(a)$$
What is your corrected result?
This will lead to
$$q(t) = \frac{1000}{\ln 2} 2^t + c$$
Wich you can easily verify to satisfy the constraints.

Comment: I think its $q=1000\cdot \frac{2^{t}}{2\ln2}+c$

Comment: Almost, where does the $\frac12$ come from in your calculations?
Note that $\frac d{dt} 2^t = \ln 2 \cdot 2^t$ so $\int 2^t\, dt = \frac1{\ln2} 2^t$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{dq}{dt}=1000\cdot 2^t \rightarrow dq=1000\cdot 2^t dt \rightarrow \int dq=1000\cdot \int 2^t dt \rightarrow q=1000. \frac{1}{\ln 2} 2^t +c$

Comment: How did you integrate $2^t$

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt} a^t = \ln(a) a^2 \rightarrow \frac{d}{dt} \frac{1}{\ln(a)} a^t =  a^t \rightarrow d \, \frac{1}{\ln(a)} a^t = a^t dt \rightarrow \int d \, \frac{1}{\ln(a)} a^t = \int a^t dt \rightarrow \frac{1}{\ln(a)} a^t = \int a^t dt$